# Seperate index for DateTime columns within a composite primary key

Tags: sql-server-2008

A co-worker created a table similar to this:

```
EmpID
ShiftStartDateTime
ShiftEndDateTime
PayRate
AnotherColumn
AnotherColumn
```

The primary key includes all columns (not sure why, I need to discuss with him).

The queries will primarily involve filtering against the EmpID and StartDateTime columns.

Assumming all columns need to part of the primary key, should seperate index(es) be added on the EmpID and StartDateTime columns?

Comment: `(EmpID, ShiftStartDateTime)` seems the most likely primary key candidate to me. Although in this particular case I might prefer a surrogate `ID`.

Comment: Putting all of the columns in the index ensures that queries can be satisfied by just reading the index file.  Back in the beginning of relational databases this was done to maximize SELECT performance at the expense of changes.  This SELECT performance enhancement is generally no longer necessary.

Comment: @Andriy M: I agree. I found out that he included the extra columns in the index because he was getting unique key violoation when he tried to populate the table from the source data. To me this indicates we have duplicate shifts in the data. He is checking into it further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, having all fields in primary key looks very suspicious to me. If it's also a clustered index, you will have a great overhead while inserting/updating records. Normally, you never update value of primary key.  As to your question, that depends on the order of columns in you PK. If it's `EmpID, ShiftStartDateTime,ShiftEndDateTime,PayRate,AnotherColumn, AnotherColumn` and you queries will filter by `EmpID and  StartDateTime`, then this index will be used, and you don't need extra (which will be a huge waste of space)

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

I would add single index over both fields.

The index will only be used for a **seek** if the fields you are filtering on are the first ones in the index.

Think of a phone book, where you can't find everyone named "John" easily, but you can easily find people with a last name of "Smith", and then find all "John"s in that list.  **You need the first key to be able to use the second.**

If one of those two fields is more commonly used than the other, I would add it first so it can be used without the other field being included.